# Is it possible to sync title and description from Flickr to Lightroom?

Tags: software, metadata, lightroom-3, flickr

I wonder if I can sync metadata such as title and description from Flickr to LR without using any third party software, just with built in Flickr Plugin. If so, how can I do it?

Comment: Having tried this myself just now, I can't see any way to synchronise the Flickr metadata. The comments are imported to Lightroom, though I have no idea why.

Comment: Too bad, because I've edited many titles and descriptions right in the Flickr. Still looking for solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in LR 3.6 unfortunately.

Comment: The Flickr and Lightroom APIs are open. So maybe one day someone is going to write a better sync plugin.

Comment: Maybe! I haven't checked this in 4.3, maybe they've done it already..